# What are ways to cache queries from SQLite database?

Tags: android, performance, sqlite

I am developing the following functionality:
an user picks a date and gets `ListView` populated by `SimpleCoursorLoader` (queries are executed in the background).
User frequently choices adjacent dates and there might be a lot of duplicate queries.
I tested the application and discovered that in case of high frequency requests - it runs very slow.
In order to speedup my application I decided to implement cache where results of queries will be stored. Key - date and value-?
Is it worth doing and what techniques could you advice?

Answer (score 1):

1) Yes, it's really worth doing since DB access is relatively slow (even with such a great thing like SQLite)

2) Considering what I've got from your post I'd suggest using [LongSparseArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/util/LongSparseArray.html): 
**key** will be date from database (`long`), 
**stored value** - your cached data object (`Bundle` etc).
 The reasons are it's:

- naturally sorted
- sort order is maintained on changes
- fast
- memory efficient

3) When you need to load overlapping/adjacent interval you have to check bounds and load only absent part

4) If a situation is possible when you cache *non-adjacent* intervals - you need to manage loaded intervals bounds as well. But if you do it only for list scroll purposes you may omit this (if you don't stop loading data on fling gesture)

About my experience: I've got about 3 times payoff using caching. But actual results depends on database scheme etc. You may get even more

Answer (score 0):

I found MatrixCursor useful for the purpose of caching. I keep HashMap.
Logic: if no request has been done - issue it, get Cursor, convert it to MatrixCursor and write to cache.

Here is the snippet for convertion:

```
private MatrixCursor cursorToMatrixCursor(Cursor c) {
        MatrixCursor result = new MatrixCursor(c.getColumnNames());
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                ArrayList<String> columnValues = new ArrayList<>();
                final int nOfColumns = c.getColumnCount();
                for(int col = 0; col < nOfColumns; ++col)
                    columnValues.add(c.getString(col));
                result.addRow(columnValues);
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
        return result;
    }
```